# Config Environment varible into webpack file config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I would like to use the process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL in the publicPath

```
output: {
  path: build,
  filename: "[name]/main.js",
  publicPath: "https://stb2cdesa01.blob.core.windows.net/root/",
},
```

this is my .env file

REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL='https://stb2cdesa01.blob.core.windows.net/root'

try this but it doesn't work

```
output: {
  path: build,
  filename: "[name]/main.js",
  publicPath:process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL,
},
```

Comment: How to do this is explained right in the docs: https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/